# Restricting max file size per resource

Tags: java, spring, apache, cxf, jax-rs

I am using Apache-cxf (JAX-RS) coupled with spring framework. I have the following sample code in my beans.xml.

```
    <jaxrs:server id="services" address="${http.server}">
        <jaxrs:properties>
            <entry key="attachment-max-size" value="1024" />
        </jaxrs:properties>
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <bean id="mainResource" class="com.abc.rest.api.MainResource">
            <lookup-method name="createEmployeeCollectionResource"
                    bean="employeeCollectionResource" />
            </bean>
        ...
        ...other beans
        ...
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
```

I also have the following code

```
<bean id="employeeCollectionResource"
    class="com.abc.rest.services.EmployeeCollectionResourceImpl">
    <lookup-method name="createNewEmployeeResource" bean="employeeResource" />
</bean>
<bean id="employeeResource" scope="prototype"
    class="com.abc.rest.services.EmployeeResourceImpl">
</bean>
```

I have set the max file size during upload as 1KB for all the services in general.

How can I restrict the `attachment-max-size` for few beans in particular? Example - 5MB for few beans and 2MB for few others etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to organise your endpoints/resources in separate `<jaxrs:server >` tags with their own settings for attachment size:

```xml
<jaxrs:server id="services">
    <jaxrs:properties>
        <entry key="attachment-max-size" value="1024" />
    </jaxrs:properties>
    ....
</jaxrs:server>


<jaxrs:server id="largeFileServices">
    <jaxrs:properties>
        <entry key="attachment-max-size" value="1000000" />
    </jaxrs:properties>
    ....
</jaxrs:server>
```

https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html